# Shared libraries with a path on names

Tags: path, shared, ld, rpath

I'm making a project which uses lots of it's own shared libraries; my intention is to create a library name within a directory, so, e.g., instead of -lfoo (to find /usr/lib/libfoo.so or /opt/lib/libfoo.so or so on), I would use -lfoo/bar (to find /usr/lib/libfoo/bar.so or /opt/lib/libfoo/bar.so or so on).

I made a real small code to test:

```
const char *mylib(void) {
  return "it woooorks! =D";
};
```

And compiled it with: `gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-rpath,libfoo/ lib.c -o /usr/lib/libfoo/bar.so`.

Then, in the test program, I use `gcc -lfoo/bar test.c`, and it compiles (it finds the `mylib()` symbol from my library), but when I try to run the program (`./a.out`), the dynamic linker complains that it can't find the library. In my case, using Mac OS X Lion:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: bar.so
  Referenced from: /Users/takanuva/tmp/lib/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the answer is "everything", so... how should I accomplish the desired effect, to look for libfoo/bar.so instead of libfoo.so on the library paths?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the library is not located in a standard path (and /opt is such a path that is normally not searched), you must specify the paths with -L/-rpath, as in `gcc blah.c -L/opt/whatever -Wl,-rpath,/opt/whatever -lbar`. Do NOT attempt to use path separators in the `-l` argument.

Comment: The idea is to have a path relative to the standard search paths, so it could look for /usr/lib/whatever/test.so, /usr/local/lib/whatever/test.so, /opt/lib/whatever/test.so, and so on.